# How to change the window size in Panda3D?

Tags: panda3d

A **Panda3D** program opens with a certain window size. I cannot find any call in `GraphicsWindow` to set or change the window size.

How do I change the window size?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can change the initial window size in your [Config.prc](http://www.panda3d.org/manual/index.php/Configuring_Panda) file, OR you can prepend the following code in your main python file:

```
from panda3d.core import loadPrcFileData 
  
loadPrcFileData('', 'win-size 1024 768')
```

If you want to change the window size at runtime the following code should do the trick:

```
w, h = 1024, 768 

props = WindowProperties() 
props.setSize(w, h) 

self.win.requestProperties(props)
```

Hope it helps.